# topological K - space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called $T_B$ if every compact subset is closed.

Let $X$ be  $T_B$ and $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ be one-point compatification of $X$.

A topological space is called $K$- space if it has the property that any sunset $F$ s.t $F \cap K$ is closed for all closed compact $K$ is itself closed.

Why does the bellow

> **Let $X$ be  $T_B$. If  $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ is $T_B$ , then $X$ is $K$- space?**

Answer (score 2):

(The correct term is $k$-*space*, not $K$-*space*.) If $X$ is not a $k$-space, there is a set $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\cap K$ is closed for each compact $K\subseteq X$, but $A$ is not closed.

Let $C=A\cup\{\infty\}$, and suppose that $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $C$. Fix $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\infty\in U_0$; then $X\setminus U_0$ is a closed, compact subset of $X$, so $C\setminus U_0=C\cap(X\setminus U_0)$ is a closed subset of the compact set $X\setminus U_0$ and is therefore compact in $X$. There is therefore a finite $\mathscr{V}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ covering $C\setminus U_0$, and $\mathscr{V}\cup\{U_0\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covering $C$. Thus, $C$ is a compact set in $X^*$. $X^*$ is $T_B$, so $C$ is closed in $X^*$, and we get an immediate contradiction; what is that contradiction?

Comment: I can not reach to real contradiction. But I though, If $C$ is closed in $X^*$, is contradiction with k- space definition!

Comment: @Ebi: If $C$ is closed in $X^*$, then $C\cap X$ is closed in $X$; what is $C\cap X$, and why is this a contradiction?

Comment: according k- space definition,  for every compact subset like C which $C \cap X$ is closed in  C, $X \subseteq X^*$ is closed, but I still don`t understand contradiction!

Comment: @Ebi: The definition of $k$-space is irrelevant at this point. What is $C\cap X$?

Comment: If C is closed in $X^∗$, so closed in $X^∗$. $A = C \cap X$ must be closed.

Comment: @Ebi: Yes, and that gives you the contradiction that you want.